How can I ensure to keep equal pixel density?
I work with an artist that draws tilesets and texture atlases for my 2D game.
Since we are not very experienced, we face a problem, when one texture atlas differs to other in size. That means that I cannot use tiles' width and height to scale all the models properly to match the same pixel density. I have to scale some models up and down to keep pixel density same, but it is not very convenient and produces a lot of magic numbers for each model's size. I believe that happens cause of UV offsets difference, when one frame one atlas has UV offset for frame as 0.1, 0.1 and other 0.2, 0.2.
What I want is to know how to draw texture atlases with different number of frames (e.g. texture atlas A consists of 10 frames whereas atlas B contains 15). How can we ensure that texture atlases will allow us to scale models according to certain constants (in my case, tile dimensions).
UPD:
Here I attach the example of bad scaling. As you can see, one character has a height of 3 tiles and width of 2 tiles.
The size of their atlas is 951 x 824.

In the same time, the NPC should have the same dimensions, so I apply same scale matrix to their model.
However, the model comes smaller.
The size of their atlas is 3290x2691 due to them having a lot more frames for animation.

If we don't mind pixel densities' difference, the question still stays - I need both models to have the same size in tiles.

It would help to attach a couple if exemplar images/atlases with "bad" scales to the question. As of now it is hard to guess what is going on.

@Kromster done. Please review the question now

So it turned out that OpenGL scale matrix should have scaled entities to their real size in pixels. Given that pixel densities of tiles and entities match each other, the solution only needs to calculate the pixel dimension of one frame in atlas. So if the artist draws the entity N tiles high, N does not really matter.


For each texure calculate the texel size:
TexelWidth = 1.0 / widthInPixels;
TexelHeight = 1.0 / heigtInPixels;

TLU = X * TexelWidth; // top left X offset
BLU = TLU; // bottom left X
TLV = Y * TexelHeight; // Left top Y offset
TRV = TLV; // top right Y

BRU = (X + Width) * TexelWidth; // right scale and clipping
TRU = BRU;
BRV = (Y + Height) * TexelHeight; // bottom scale and clipping
BLV = BRV;

The UVs applied to the quad then become:
(TLU,TLV) ... (TRU,TRV)
.                     .
.                     .
.                     .
(BLU,BLV) ... (BRU,BRV)


Layout
Pick a tile size per texture and stick to it.
If you have a small Mario whose size is 15x15, every other sub-texture should be similarly offset and divided by the 15x15 grid.
The large Mario takes up 2 squares on the 15x15 grid becoming 30x15 with a -15 Y object position offset on the change from small to large.
Each texture atlas can have its own grid size, but the source and target pixel density is (almost) always 1.
Use batch precomposition to combine the scene into a single buffer then scale to the output screen size in the shader on the GPU. (crop or pad the source buffer, if needed)
Otherwise, each object would require independent scaling and translation of the UVs, requiring separate Draw calls.
Models
Your question includes the term models. If you are using 3d models for 2d rendering, say for lighting or animation purposes, use a simple box projection UV and apply separate textures for the four sides. Just as long as all 3d models are created with the same scale, as in side by side in the modelling program, only one scaling factor will be needed for all models to fit and align with pixel art, or composition as described above, set on a 3d single quad screen aligned plane surface with a 1 to 1 scale factor when viewed via an orthographic projection.

Hey, thank you for the answer. However it is still unclear to me, how do I manage scaling. All atlases are drawn relatively to each other and have the same pixel density, the problem is that if one atlas contains more frames than other, UV coordinates differ and I should apply extra scaling, which could be something like tileSize * 2.5 when the frame should be drawn with the size of 2 tiles.

I edited my question for you to take a look

@Steyrix I have updated the answer, accordingly. I am sorry for my misunderstanding.

I scored you answer, however I poorly described my problem so the solution was much more simple
